# Need help to identify SOT23-5 component

Tags: identification, surface-mount, sot23

I'm in need for some help to identify 2 components marked with:

- S3TJ
- S2TI

[image: S3TJ]

[image: S2TI]

There are found in PC Controller from 8bitdo and it contains 3.7v battery and charges using USB.

Comment: The manufacturer is MICRONE and the parts are probably LDOs. MICRONE doesn't seem to specify the markings in their datasheet, so you will have to measure it to be sure which one it is.

Answer (score 1):

S2TI 5V to 3,3V converter

- PIN 1 - 5V IN
- PIN 2 - GND
- PIN 3 - 5V IN
- PIN 4 - NC
- PIN 5 - 3,3V OUT
- PIN 1 and 3 connected

This pinout was written based on PCB with S2TI

Comment: Either pin 1 or pin 3 is probably an enable input.